# Prevent Google Drive from automatically installing other Google apps like docs, sheets and slides

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-apps

Google Drive keeps installing other Google Suite apps. I know these are just links to the web services and I can delete them. However, they are installed again after an update.

I installed drive via homebrew on macOS 14.2.

All the guides I have found are only for Chrome. Is there a way to permanently block the installation of those apps via Google Drive?

Comment: Unfortunately, that’s how Google operates.  I experienced the same issue and decided to dump Google Drive for MS OneDrive.  It’s a stand alone app and will not install the Office suite without your consent .

Comment: Thank you very much. Guess I'm switching to OneDrive as well.